# Flutter not building web

Tags: flutter, web

```
szunyoghtamas@Szunyogh-MacBook-Air ezduels % flutter doctor -v [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale hu-HU)
    • Flutter version 3.16.3 on channel stable at /Users/szunyoghtamas/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0366e0a3f (2 days ago), 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 54a7145303
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/szunyoghtamas/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A507
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.78.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Tamás iPhone-ja (mobile) • 00008110-000658D20A20401E • ios            • iOS 17.1.2 21B101
    • macOS (desktop)          • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)             • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.71

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

name: web
description: EzDuels web version.
publish_to: "none"
version: 0.3.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  mobile:
    path: ../mobile
  common:
    path: ../common

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.2
  flutter_credit_card: ^3.0.7

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/animation/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/rank/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/background/
    - assets/authentication_assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/audio/
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

> Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:7:8:
> Error: Error when reading 'lib/web.dart': No such file or directory
> import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;
> ^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:9:8:
> Error: Error when reading 'lib/web.dart': No such file or directory
> import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;
> ^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:11:8:
> Error: Error when reading 'lib/web.dart': No such file or directory
> import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;
> ^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:31:47:
> Error: Type 'web.HTMLElement' not found. typedef _WebSelectionCallBack
> = void Function(web.HTMLElement, web.MouseEvent);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:31:64:
> Error: Type 'web.MouseEvent' not found. typedef _WebSelectionCallBack
> = void Function(web.HTMLElement, web.MouseEvent);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:17:30:
> Error: Type 'web.XMLHttpRequest' not found. typedef HttpRequestFactory
> = web.XMLHttpRequest Function();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:23:1:
> Error: Type 'web.XMLHttpRequest' not found. web.XMLHttpRequest
> _httpClient() { ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:41:40:
> Error: Undefined name 'window'.   final String navigatorPlatform =
> web.window.navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
> ^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:61:11:
> Error: Undefined name 'window'.   if (web.window.matchMedia('only
> screen and (pointer: fine)').matches) {
> ^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:84:62:
> Error: 'HTMLElement' isn't a type.
> _registeredViewType = _registerWebSelectionCallback((web.HTMLElement element, web.MouseEvent event) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:84:87:
> Error: 'MouseEvent' isn't a type.
> _registeredViewType = _registerWebSelectionCallback((web.HTMLElement element, web.MouseEvent event) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:97:19:
> Error: 'Range' isn't a type.
> final web.Range range = web.document.createRange();
> ^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:97:37:
> Error: Undefined name 'document'.
> final web.Range range = web.document.createRange();
> ^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:99:19:
> Error: 'Selection' isn't a type.
> final web.Selection? selection = web.window.getSelection();
> ^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:99:46:
> Error: Undefined name 'window'.
> final web.Selection? selection = web.window.getSelection();
> ^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:110:17:
> Error: 'HTMLElement' isn't a type.
> final web.HTMLElement htmlElement = web.document.createElement('div') as web.HTMLElement;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:110:47:
> Error: Undefined name 'document'.
> final web.HTMLElement htmlElement = web.document.createElement('div') as web.HTMLElement;
> ^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:110:84:
> Error: 'HTMLElement' isn't a type.
> final web.HTMLElement htmlElement = web.document.createElement('div') as web.HTMLElement;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:117:17:
> Error: 'HTMLStyleElement' isn't a type.
> final web.HTMLStyleElement styleElement = web.document.createElement('style') as web.HTMLStyleElement;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:117:53:
> Error: Undefined name 'document'.
> final web.HTMLStyleElement styleElement = web.document.createElement('style') as web.HTMLStyleElement;
> ^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:117:92:
> Error: 'HTMLStyleElement' isn't a type.
> final web.HTMLStyleElement styleElement = web.document.createElement('style') as web.HTMLStyleElement;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:118:11:
> Error: Undefined name 'document'.
> web.document.head!.append(styleElement); ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:118:11:
> Error: Undefined name 'document'.
> web.document.head!.append(styleElement);
> ^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:119:17:
> Error: 'CSSStyleSheet' isn't a type.
> final web.CSSStyleSheet sheet = styleElement.sheet!;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:123:54:
> Error: 'Event' isn't a type.
> htmlElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (web.Event event) {
> ^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:124:19:
> Error: 'MouseEvent' isn't a type.
> final web.MouseEvent mouseEvent = event as web.MouseEvent;
> ^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:24:14:
> Error: Method not found: 'XMLHttpRequest'.   return
> web.XMLHttpRequest();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:121:27:
> Error: 'XMLHttpRequest' isn't a type.
> final Completer<web.XMLHttpRequest> completer =
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:122:25:
> Error: 'XMLHttpRequest' isn't a type.
> Completer<web.XMLHttpRequest>();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:123:17:
> Error: 'XMLHttpRequest' isn't a type.
> final web.XMLHttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:133:45:
> Error: 'Event' isn't a type.
> request.addEventListener('load', (web.Event e) {
> ^^^^^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:129:9:
> Error: Type 'invalid-type' is not a valid type for external
> `dart:js_interop` APIs. The only valid types are: @staticInterop
> types, JS types from `dart:js_interop`, void, bool, num, double, int,
> String, and any extension type that erases to one of these types. Use
> one of the valid types instead.
> }.toJS);
> ^ ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:149:9:
> Error: Type 'invalid-type' is not a valid type for external
> `dart:js_interop` APIs. The only valid types are: @staticInterop
> types, JS types from `dart:js_interop`, void, bool, num, double, int,
> String, and any extension type that erases to one of these types. Use
> one of the valid types instead.
> }.toJS);
> ^ Failed to compile application.

**Could someone help me, since I switched to the latest flutter version, I can't build for the web and I don't understand what's wrong.**